# helm: Error: no available release name found - same error, different problem

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I've done:

```
brew install kubernetes-helm
helm init
helm install stable/mysql
```

and am getting:

```
Error: no available release name found
```

Any suggestions?

This doesn't help btw - [Helm: Error: no available release name found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43499971/helm-error-no-available-release-name-found)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Kubernetes version/configuration you probably have to configure rbac for tiller:

`$ kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
$ helm init --service-account tiller`

as per https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3055

Answer (score 1):

If rbac and namespace has not been created/enabled.
Run this command if you have defined a version in your Chart.yaml 
**helm install --name "mysql" stable/mysql --version Mysql.1.3**

If rbac and namespace has been enabled, first list the namespaces using
kubectl get namespaces --all-namespaces=true
This shall list if your namespace is created. 
Then run this command
**helm install -n namespace_name --name mysql stable/mysql --version Mysql1.3**

Answer (score 0):

Run `$ helm repo update` before install command.

Answer (score 0):

**Ran into same issue , the  default error log looks of not much help**

```
$ helm install stable/mysql --debug
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '36127'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:36127"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] Fetched stable/mysql to /home/ubuntu/.helm/cache/archive/mysql-1.6.2.tgz

[debug] CHART PATH: /home/ubuntu/.helm/cache/archive/mysql-1.6.2.tgz

Error: no available release name found
```

**playing around with `helm --help` it suggest that if we do not provide `--name` it is auto generated (Note I was using helm 2.16.1)**

```
-n, --name string              The release name. If unspecified, it will autogenerate one for you
```

**But i decided to --name anyway and then i finally get a more meaning full error give me the root cause to failure**

```
$ helm install stable/mysql --name=happy-panda --debug
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '39848'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:39848"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] Fetched stable/mysql to /home/ubuntu/.helm/cache/archive/mysql-1.6.2.tgz

[debug] CHART PATH: /home/ubuntu/.helm/cache/archive/mysql-1.6.2.tgz

Error: release happy-panda failed: namespaces "default" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

**Then i used the steps shared by @abinet above** to fix the issue by using below three commands.

```
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller

kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller

kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'
```